# given a graph of density function, what can we conclude about expected value

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

given the following graph (the density function), what can we conclude about the expected value? I got stuck a little bit with that question and I would appreciate your help!

I found out that **C** must be equal $\frac{2}{7}$ that the distribution function would be valid (=1).

furthermore, I know that $E[x]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$. but here it's equal to: $\int_{1}^{2}x(\frac{1}{7}x-\frac{1}{7})dx+\int_{2}^{4}x(\frac{2}{7})dx+\int_{4}^{6}x(-\frac{1}{7}x+\frac{4}{7})dx$  (after calculating the functions that describe each part of the graph).

Now - from evaluating the above sum of integrals I get the value of about 0.2 while it doesn't seem reasonable! from the graph it should be more then 3 as I understand.

would appreciate your help and advice!

[image]

Comment: You haven't calculated the functions for the triangular parts correctly.  The slope of the first line should be $\frac27$, while the last line should evaluate to $\frac27$ at $x = 4$.

Comment: @Shagnik so $\int_{1}^{2}x(-\frac{2}{7}x-\frac{2}{7})dx+\int_{2}^{4}x(\frac{2}{7})dx+\int_{4}^{6}x(-\frac{1}{7}x+\frac{6}{7})dx$ ?? yet I get about 2.2.. what am I doing wrong??

Comment: The first integral should be $\int_1^2 x ( \frac27 x - \frac27) dx$.  The rest looks good to me.  That will increase the value by $\frac43$, which looks more like what one would expect by eyeballing the problem.

Comment: @Shagnik it was my mistake, I meant to write $\frac{2}{7}$ instead of $-\frac{2}{7}$. but with that sum of integrals I get the value $\frac{47}{21}$ and it's about 2.3. it doesn't seem reasonable, because from the graph, the expected value should reach more then the middle of the graph.. more to the right then the middle (then x=3).

Comment: Okay, in that case your integral formula is correct. Check your integration, because the sum of the integrals should be $\frac{23}{7}$, which is indeed to the right of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

I have $c=\frac{2}{7}$ as well. The area is

$0.5c+2c+c=1$

$3.5c=1 \Rightarrow c=\frac{2}{7}$

The pdf is

$f(x)=\begin{cases} c\cdot (x-1), \ 1\leq x <2 \\ c  ,  \quad \ 2\leq x <4 \\  c-1/2\cdot c\cdot (x-4), \ 4\leq x <6 \end{cases}$

The slope of the third interval is $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}=\frac{c-0}{4-6}$

We can use the integral calculation as well to get the value of c.

$\int_1^2 c\cdot(x-1) \, dx+\int_2^4 c \, dx+\int_4^6 c-1/2\cdot c\cdot (x-4) \, dx=1$

$=\frac{c}{2}+2c+c=1$

And the expected value is

$E(X)=\int_1^2 2/7\cdot (x-1)\cdot x \, dx+\int_2^4 2/7\cdot x  \,  dx+\int_4^6 (2/7-1/2\cdot 2/7\cdot (x-4))\cdot x \,  dx$

Thus $E(X)=\frac{23}{7}=3\frac27$

Comment: Why is your middle-part $\int_4^6 x \, dx$ and not $\int_4^6 2/7 \cdot x \, dx$?

Comment: I was on the wrong track. I added the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Your density can be split in three parts $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$:

$f_1(x) \cdot x = -2/7 \cdot x + 2/7 \cdot x^2$

$f_2(x) \cdot x =  2/7 \cdot x$

$f_3(x) \cdot x = 6/7\cdot x -1/7 \cdot x^2$

Then then antiderivatives are:

$I_1(x) = -2/14\cdot x^2 + 2/21 \cdot x^3$

$I_2(x) = 2/14 \cdot x^2$

$I_3(x) = 6/14 \cdot x^2 -1/21 \cdot x^3$

And finally the sum of the integrals:

$E = (-2/14 \cdot 2^2 + 2/21 \cdot 2^3 + 2/14 \cdot 1^2 - 2/21 \cdot 1^3) + 
  ( 2/14 \cdot 4^2 -  2/14 \cdot 2^2) + 
  (6/14 \cdot 6^2 -1/21 \cdot 6^3 - 6/14 \cdot 4^2 + 1/21 \cdot 4^3) =
(-8+2+32-8+216-96)/14  +
  (16-2-216+64)/21 = 23/7 \approx 3.285714$